# Does Json.NET guarantee that IEnumerables will only be evaluated once?

Tags: json.net

I'm looking to find this some place, but I can't find it.

Can I rely that Json.NET will only evaluate `IEnumerable` once?  I'd rather not write my code to ensure this, but if I have an expensive `IEnumerable` evaluation, I'd hate to have it executed several times by the serializer.

Of course, I can always ensure this myself, but I am wondering if Json.NET guarantees this?